# Why $A=\{x\in \Omega \mid u(x)=\max_\Omega u\}$ is open?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega $ open, bounded and connected. Let $u\in \mathcal C^2(\Omega )\cap \mathcal C(\bar \Omega )$ harmonic in $\Omega $. Let $x\in \Omega $ s.t. $u(x)=\max_\Omega  u$ and $r>0$ s.t. $B(x,r)\subset \subset \Omega $.

Q1) Why $u$ is constant on $B(x,r)$ ?

By mean value property, for all $y\in B(x,r)$, $$u(y)=\frac{1}{|B(y,r)|}\int_{B(y,r)}u,$$
but why is it constant ?

---

Q2) Why $A=\{x\in \Omega \mid u(x)=\max_\Omega  u\}$ is open ?

Indeed, $u$ is continuous and $A=u^{-1}(\{\max_\Omega  u\})$ and thus should be closed. So why open ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in A$. By the mean value property, and for a suitably small $r$, we have : $$
u(x) = \frac 1{|B(x,r)|} \int_{B(x,r)} u(y)dy
$$
From what we know, since $u(y) \leq u(x)$ for all $y \in \Omega$, we have that:
$$
u(x) \geq \frac 1{|B(x,r)|} \int_{B(x,r)} u(y)dy
$$

I encourage you to prove a converse to this statement : if equality happens above, and we assume that $x \in A$, then indeed $u$ is constant on $B(x,r)$. Think about how you would do this.

Once this is true, then $A$ will contain an open neighbourhood of $x$, namely the entire ball of radius $r$, and hence would be open.